# How to define your own physics body for node added in gamescene.sks

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm making a game using spritekit and swift. I added a bunch of rocks to use as barriers in the gamescene.sks, and want the rocks to disappear on contact. The body type definitions in the gamescene sks are too big, and I was wondering how I can define my own physics body for these nodes. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different way to achieve that.
If we make it by code, here are the 2 more simple ways of achieving it: 
Circular body:

```
circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: circle.size.width/2) // Here you put any numeric value for your radius
```

With a Rectangular body:

```
square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: square.frame.size)
```

In your case, you can use a circular body with a smaller radius than your rocks.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how I can set the bodies that I define programatically for a spritenode I added in gamescene.sks. I set custom bodies around all the rocks but I am unsure of how to remove the images that I set in sks after collision.

Comment: You can create a custom class for your node rocks and add there the physics. Then you can create a variable that holds reference to that custom SKSpriteNode Class and can assign its physics values. You should remove the physics body from within the Sks.

Comment: How do I reference my custom class with the image I added in the SKS?